# TDD - Can't run MSTest Tests

Tags: c#, tdd, resharper, mstest

I'm working on getting into TDD more.  So here's my test class.  The problem is that I know my test should fail but it's not even allowing the ReSharper test runner to run, the build fails before R# has a chance to even run the test to tell me it's red for failing.

```
[TestClass]
public class Car
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void nothing(){}

    [TestMethod]
    public void UponInitialization_ServiceIsNotNull()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(carService != null);
    }
}
```

so the build fails when I invoke the R# test runner on the 2nd test method for the carService which has yet to be created as a physical class.

Comment: Is the project, and subsequent test project, on your local drive?  If they are on a shared drive then this may be your problem. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/502353/running-unit-tests-from-network-drive

Comment: no local drive, my own laptop

Comment: I heard about resharper has some problems with new visual studio. Did you have used the Vs 2012?

Comment: this is TDD, the class carService does not exist.  The R# test runner should technically run that test method and result in red because that class does not exist so the test fails.  Then like true TDD, go back and implement the class or whatever it takes to make it green again.  I can't even get to the test completing...so not sure how people who are doing TDD are getting their tests to run if the compiler is complaining that the type doesn't exist which is what is expected but certainly don't want it to fail completely and not run the unit test!

Comment: @Toan, you're on the "R# is slow, R# causes problems rant that happened 8 years ago".  
R# has never had issues with VS lately, that's old folk lore.  Yea 10 years ago it did, but that's no longer the case and the test runner rocks, I wouldn't trade it for anything.  All other test runners suck compared to R#'s.  R# is the best God damn tool you can have as developer.  Devs should be required to use it because it benefits the entire team, the codebase improves, and people learn from R# in fact.  Too many benefits for people not to be using it.

Comment: lol np Toan.  I'm passionate about R#, it rocks man.  I just get really annoyed for example when I go to dev shops where you get Leads who have their head up their ass still who also have an ego and have to speak for everyone saying you shouldn't use R#.... using old problems R# used to have as an excuse NOT to use R# when those problems have been long gone for years.  Then I've been on teams that look at you funny if you don't use R# because they know it's so much more productive....and no, VS doesn't do all that R# can do, not even close so it's worth it to get yourself a license.

Comment: now if anyone can answer my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is TDD workflow. The build fails. Hence the "Red" in Red, Green, Refactor.

Not compiling is the same as a failing test. Surely the sources you've seen say something similar to that?

Seeing the color Red somewhere does not signal that you're in the Red portion of Red, Green, Refactor. Red is basically the point where your code is wrong. Either tests fail, or it doesn't build at all. That is Red.

Comment: yea but I should see red in the test runner, I'm not even getting that

Comment: the test doesn't even show as being ran in the test runner is what I'm saying

Comment: Seeing the color Red does not mean you haven't hit "Red" in Red, Green, Refactor. Red just means it didn't pass, or it didn't build. A blocker, so to speak. Red means, as it currently stands, this code is wrong.

Comment: dude it should turn red, that's common when you create a type that doesn't exist, my tests turn green!  so they should be turning red, that's a core trait of TDD test runners...the test runner reports green or red.

Comment: So, just so we're clear: You're saying code that doesn't even build should be testable in a test runner?

Comment: so outside of asserts failing you're saying in TDD, the test runner doesn't show a fail in red also when types do not exist?

Comment: Exactly. Why? Because it hasn't loaded in the assembly to run tests with. So what does it do? It holds the last successfully built test assembly in memory.. because it hasn't been re-compiled yet.. because it can't.. the compiler won't build it. That's how test runners (that I have seen) work. They load the assembly with the tests and reflect over it to find the attributes and methods. Then they call each one and print the result. They can't do that if the assembly doesn't build.

Comment: Yes.. when Asserts fail, the assembly built successfully and the test runner knows the assert failed.. because its executing compiled code.